# No audio after installing droidcam on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, droidcam

I installed droidcam by following the steps given [here](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/). However after installing the sound stopped working. The speakers don't work, neither do headphone. I uninstalled it and it started working again. Any help on how to use droidcam and be able to keep the sound working for other applications?

It seems that the problem occurs after I run the following command as given in the above link.
The sound works fine just fine prior to this command.

```
sudo ./install-sound
```

Is there any way to reverse its effects once I am done with Droidcam?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the audio settings you should now see two devices. At least in my case, the new one installed by DroidCam is the default each time I restart the system. Each time you have to manually alter to the original one in order to have your audio working.
However, this is not a definite solution; I'm also looking to a way to reverse this effects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these two options work?

- [DroidCam for Linux](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/)
  Sound support is also available. After the above installation succeeds, you can then run:

  ```
  sudo ./install-sound
  ```

  in the same directory. This will load the Linux ALSA Loopback sound card which the Droidcam client will use for audio input.
- [ArchWiki: Microphone not detected by PulseAudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone)

Comment: How to know where I installed droidcam?

Answer (score 0):

I found this entire ALSA PulseAudio integration issue with DroidCam a real headache. So I crafted a solution for myself.

You can find it here and with a very long winded explanation of the problems:

```
https://github.com/aidyw/droidcam-snd-manager
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score -1):

i do uninstall droidcam and then restart the PC. Alhamdulillah after that the sound comeback normal.

Comment: The question's author has told us that the problem started after installing the software.  I think it is implied that they want to keep using that software but want to fix the sound problem.  Uninstalling the software does not really solve the problem.  Also, please leave references to religion and politics and other off-topic, controversial topics out of your contributions here. It's not appropriate.